# Showing Thumbnail from Previous and Next Posts

Tags: posts, post-thumbnails, previous-post-link, next-post-link

Is there a simple way to use the post thumbnail when calling `previous_post_link()` and `next_post_link()`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This could be acheived by using the `get_previous_post()` and `get_the_post_thumbnail()` functions. Then just pass the thumbnail value into the second parameter of `previous_post_link()`.

```
$prevPost = get_previous_post();
$prevThumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail( $prevPost->ID );
previous_post_link( '%link', $prevThumbnail );
```